# /admin/orphan-wikis displays wrong info

Tags: bug, status-completed

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/admin/orphan-wikis is displaying no orphaned tag wikis (even though [testing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing) has one), instead displaying a link to `/faq` whose display text is "Wiki placeholder WikiPlaceholder-FaqWhatKindOfQuestions" and then the ♦-editable part of the FAQ.

Comment: Now it lists the [tag:testing] wiki, but still the "...placeholder...". But I suppose that that's by design (?).

Comment: Is this one of those classified mod only URLs?

Comment: Yeah, @ShmuelBrin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That link does point to a list of orphan wikis now. If this was a bug, it's probably fixed now.